# How do I install libgit2 on Alipne linux

Tags: docker, alpine-linux

I am new to Docker and trying to use an Alpine docker image for my project. I am getting the following error when I am try to build the project.

```
gopkg.in/libgit2/git2go.v22
# pkg-config --cflags libgit2
pkg-config: exec: "pkg-config": executable file not found in $PATH
```

I think I need to install libgit2 but I am not able to:

```
bash-4.3# apk add libgit2
ERROR: unsatisfiable constraints:
  libgit2 (missing):
    required by: world[libgit2]
```

Thanks for any help.

-dj

Comment: can you show your dockerfile? It's a better approach than performing install commands in your container immediatley

Answer (score 2):

As of the start 2017 `libgit2` has been added to the `main` repository. You should be able to install now with the usual

```
apk update
apk add libgit2
```

https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/packages?name=libgit2

Answer (score 0):

[libgit2](https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/package/edge/testing/x86_64/libgit2) is not present in either of `main` or `community` repositories that come preconfigured in the standard Alpine image, so you'll have to add the `testing` repo first:

`# echo http://dl-4.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/testing >> /etc/apk/repositories`

Then update package caches:

`# apk update`

And finally install `libgit2`:

`# apk add libgit2`